# Javascript refresh method doesn't work in edge?

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, page-refresh

I'm currently on a project where I need the page to refresh as soon as the music ends. With chrome and fire fox this code worked perfectly.

```js
setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 206000);
```

However this does not work in edge.

Is there another way of going around it by using javascript not meta tags as this code snippet is in an if else statement.

Comment: Please keep in mind, if one of the answers works for you, please mark them as the answer to help other peeps in the community to find their solution easier if they facing the same issue. You can do this by using grey marks (tick) beside answers (you can only choose one), for more information please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 2):

As @T.J.Crowder said in comments, **`bind` method won't work with `location.reload` on edge**, in order to get cross browsing functionality you need to avoid using it.

Try to using this one instead:

```js
setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 206000);
```

Comment: `bind` works with Edge, just not with the `location.reload` method on `Edge`. I just verified it. How utterly bizarre. It *is* a host-provided function so it's not required to be normal, but I thought Edge had fixed these issues... Yet another reason to be happy Legacy Edge is going to die.